# reids vs aioredis Execution time

Tags: python, redis, python-asyncio, aioredis

I'm trying to compare execution times for redis and aioredis in python using below 2 programs

```
## Program1.py - using python redis r.set('foo','bar') 10000 times
```

```
import datetime
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)


begin_time = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(10000):
    r.set('foo', 'bar')
print(datetime.datetime.now() - begin_time)

## Execution Time : 0:00:00.605273 seconds
```

```
## Program2.py - using python aioredis await self.redis.set('foo', 'bar') 10000 times
```

```
import asyncio
import aioredis
import time
import datetime

class Handler:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.redis = None        
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()        
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.__async__connect())
        
    async def __async__connect(self):       
        self.redis = await aioredis.create_redis_pool('redis://localhost',db=0)       

    def command(self):
        return self.loop.run_until_complete(self.__async__command())

    async def __async__command(self):
        await self.redis.set('foo', 'bar')
        
    
handler = Handler()
begin_time = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(10000):
    done = handler.command()
print(datetime.datetime.now() - begin_time)

handler.redis.close()

## Execution Time : 0:00:01.738212 seconds
```

**Question 1:** Even after using aioredis, why does my Program2.py take more execution time than Program1.py.

**Question 2:** What can be done to effectively use asyncio/aioredis in Program2.py,so Program2.py runs faster then Program1.py

Comment: you’re not using asynchronous functionality properly, you wait for each command to return before proceeding

Comment: If not better, Ideally both programs should take equal amount of execution time even with await, because both programs are doing same thing